# How to Foreach data from avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, foreach, my-model-jami

this is my category_model :

```
$this->has_many['details'] = array('foreign_model'=>'detail_category_m','foreign_table'=>'m_category_detail','foreign_key'=>'mcat_id','local_key'=>'mcat_id');
```

this is my detail_category_model :

```
$this->has_one['category'] = array('foreign_model'=>'category_m','foreign_table'=>'m_category','foreign_key'=>'mcat_id','local_key'=>'mcat_id_detail');
```

I put this code in my CI controller :

```
$data['all']= $this->detail_category_m->with_category()->get_all();
```

once I foreach and I var_dump() in view resulted like this:

```
 object(stdClass)#32 (4) { ["mcat_id_detail"]=> string(1) "1" ["mcat_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["detail_cat_name"]=> string(5) "asdas" ["category"]=> object(stdClass)#35 (2) { ["mcat_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["cat_name"]=> string(7) "Travels" } } object(stdClass)#36 (4) { ["mcat_id_detail"]=> string(1) "2" ["mcat_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["detail_cat_name"]=> string(6) "asdsad" ["category"]=> object(stdClass)#37 (2) { ["mcat_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["cat_name"]=> string(7) "Voucher" } }
```

Once I print_r in view it resulted like below:

```
stdClass Object ( [mcat_id_detail] => 1 [mcat_id] => 1 [detail_cat_name] => asdas [category] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id] => 1 [cat_name] => Travels ) ) stdClass Object ( [mcat_id_detail] => 2 [mcat_id] => 1 [detail_cat_name] => asdsad [category] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id] => 2 [cat_name] => Voucher ) )
```

Once i print_r in controller resulted like this :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id_detail] => 1 [mcat_id] => 1 [detail_cat_name] => asdas [category] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id] => 1 [cat_name] => Travels ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id_detail] => 2 [mcat_id] => 1 [detail_cat_name] => asdsad [category] => stdClass Object ( [mcat_id] => 2 [cat_name] => Voucher ) ) )
```

How do I get the cat_name and mcat_id?

I did foreach like this:

```html
foreach($all as $row) :

echo $row->cat_name;

endforeach;
```

but it goes error; please help me how to get the data I wanted.

Comment: `print_r` and post data

Comment: no its wrong data generating. Show model code as well

Comment: this is my category_model : 

$this->has_many['details'] = array('foreign_model'=>'detail_category_m','foreign_table'=>'m_category_detail','foreign_key'=>'mcat_id','local_key'=>'mcat_id');

this is my detail_category_model :

$this->has_one['category'] = array('foreign_model'=>'category_m','foreign_table'=>'m_category','foreign_key'=>'mcat_id','local_key'=>'mcat_id_detail');

please help me.

Comment: add in your question

Comment: i mean this method code `with_category()` in model

Comment: that's from avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model library 

https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model

Comment: print r array in controller and post output

Comment: You can set MY_Controller with `$this->return_as = 'array';` to avoid confusion with mixing object and arrays or vice versa. Either every model differently. use `echo "<pre>", var_dump($results), "</pre>";` or `echo "<pre>", print_r($results, true), "</pre>";` to make it readable than edit your question with formated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In View**

```
foreach ($all as $value) {

    echo $value['cat_name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $value['mcat_id'];

}
```

Comment: i did but it went error.. 

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$cat_name

Comment: what you trying to do with `avenirer`. whats that i nver heard of that

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: It's based on Jamie Rumbelow's Base Model, firstly i used rumbellow's but it's really hard to find the tutorial and then i moved to avenier which has little tutorial.. but i was wrong it's really hard to follow.

what i wanted is to get data from joining 2 tables.. but it seems complicated huhu

Comment: there is folder call model in CI. you can use that for model

Comment: actually this library makes my model really clean as well as fast.. but it's really complicated

Comment: No use at all. Simple you are wasting **your time**. For all this tme you can go ahead with your code

Comment: Couldn't agree. Using MY_Model and it is allowing make your own models in matter of seconds. +1 for [MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model/blob/version-3.0/core/MY_Model.php). SInce using it first thing in project after modeling DB, is making all models that will be used. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the with_*() method, you must mention the fields you want to retrieve:

```
$data['all']= $this->detail_category_m->with_category('fields:cat_name,mcat_id')->get_all();
```

Now, in your view, you can do something on the lines of this:

```
foreach($all as $detail)
{
  echo $detail->detail_cat_name;
  foreach($detail->category as $categ)
  {
    echo $categ->cat_name;
    echo $categ->mcat_id;
  }
}
```

Hope this helped...